# RubySMB::Error::CommunicationError: Read timeout expired when reading from the Socket (timeout=30)

Tags: windows, metasploit, smb, ruby, remote-code-execution

I've been playing around with the EternalBlue exploit recently. I've downloaded a Windows 10 iso file from 2016 and used it to set up a Windows 10 Pro VM as my sandbox. I also ran the nmap script and metasploit scanner module to ensure that it is indeed vulnerable to ms17-010.
[image]
However, when I run the exploit module, I get this:
[image]

I've spent the past hour testing out every single payload available and even tried the other eternalblue modules (which all didn't work). Does anyone know what is denying me from gaining entry to my virtual machine here?

(PS I turned off the Windows Firewall and Windows Defender real-time protection on the win10 machine already)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That module doesn't support Windows 10 targets. You can see from the targets that it supports Windows 7 and Server 2008.

```
msf6 exploit(windows/smb/ms17_010_eternalblue) > show targets 

Exploit targets:

   Id  Name
   --  ----
   0   Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2 (x64) All Service Packs


msf6 exploit(windows/smb/ms17_010_eternalblue) >
```

The ms17_010_eternalblue_win8 module (despite it's name) works on Windows 10. Says it was tested successfully on Windows 10 build 10240 and build 10586 so the build of your target is quite a bit newer but it may work.

FYI, it's a known issue that these modules are separate and targeting is difficult which is why there's [an effort to combine them](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/pull/15217) into one.